# Mask all values that occur before the max in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to take the result from [`pd.DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and use it to change the values before the index with the maximum value.

If I have`df`:

```
            Mule Creek  Saddle Mtn.  Calvert Creek
Date                                              
2011-05-01   23.400000    35.599998            8.6
2011-05-02   23.400000    35.599998            8.0
2011-05-03   23.400000    35.700001            7.6
2011-05-04   23.400000    50.000000            7.1
2011-05-05   23.100000    35.799999            6.4
2011-05-06   23.000000    35.799999            5.7
2011-05-07   40.000000    35.900002            4.7
2011-05-08   23.100000    36.500000           12.0
2011-05-09   23.299999    37.500000            4.4
2011-05-10   23.200001    37.500000            3.6
```

and I find where the maximum of each column occurs with:

```
max = df.idxmax()
```

I want to make values before the identified maximums `max` all `np.nan`

Desired result:

```
            Mule Creek  Saddle Mtn.  Calvert Creek
Date                                              
2011-05-01         NaN          NaN            NaN
2011-05-02         NaN          NaN            NaN
2011-05-03         NaN          NaN            NaN
2011-05-04         NaN    50.000000            NaN
2011-05-05         NaN    35.799999            NaN
2011-05-06         NaN    35.799999            NaN
2011-05-07   40.000000    35.900002            NaN
2011-05-08   23.100000    36.500000           12.0
2011-05-09   23.299999    37.500000            4.4
2011-05-10   23.200001    37.500000            3.6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can check where the cumulative max is the same as the max:

```
df.where(df.cummax() == df.max())

            Mule Creek  Saddle Mtn.  Calvert Creek
Date                                              
2011-05-01         NaN          NaN            NaN
2011-05-02         NaN          NaN            NaN
2011-05-03         NaN          NaN            NaN
2011-05-04         NaN    50.000000            NaN
2011-05-05         NaN    35.799999            NaN
2011-05-06         NaN    35.799999            NaN
2011-05-07   40.000000    35.900002            NaN
2011-05-08   23.100000    36.500000           12.0
2011-05-09   23.299999    37.500000            4.4
2011-05-10   23.200001    37.500000            3.6
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use `max` and `cumprod`.

```
df[(df < df.max()).cumprod().ne(1)]

            Mule Creek  Saddle Mtn.  Calvert Creek
Date                                              
2011-05-01         NaN          NaN            NaN
2011-05-02         NaN          NaN            NaN
2011-05-03         NaN          NaN            NaN
2011-05-04         NaN    50.000000            NaN
2011-05-05         NaN    35.799999            NaN
2011-05-06         NaN    35.799999            NaN
2011-05-07   40.000000    35.900002            NaN
2011-05-08   23.100000    36.500000           12.0
2011-05-09   23.299999    37.500000            4.4
2011-05-10   23.200001    37.500000            3.6
```

But perhaps there are other ways.

Comment: @ALollz Also a valid solution, you should post it!

Answer (score 1):

Simple but probably inefficient method:

```
for c in df.columns:
  df[c].loc[df[c].index[0]: df[c].idxmax()] = np.nan
```