# change the value of column to the maximum value above it in the same column

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 103, 101, np.nan, 105, 107, 100]})
```

And this is the output that I want:

```
       a    b
0  100.0    100
1  103.0    103
2  101.0    103
3    NaN    103
4  105.0    105
5  107.0    107
6  100.0    107
```

I want to create column `b` which takes values of column `a` and replace them with the maximum value that is on top of it.

For example when there is 103 in `a` I want to change all values to 103 until a greater number is in column `a`. That is why rows 2 and 3 are changed to 103 and since in row 4 there is a greater number than 103 I want to put that in column `b` until a greater number is in column `a`.

I have tried a couple of posts on stackoverflow. One of them was this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54409595/10200497). But still I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) with replace missing values by previous non `NaN`s by `ffill`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 103, 101, np.nan, 105, 107, 100]})

df['b'] = df['a'].ffill().cummax().astype(int)
#alternative
#df['b'] = df['a'].ffill(downcast='int').cummax()
print (df)
       a    b
0  100.0  100
1  103.0  103
2  101.0  103
3    NaN  103
4  105.0  105
5  107.0  107
6  100.0  107
```

If possible in real data first value is `NaN`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.nan, 103, 101, np.nan, 105, 107, 100]})

df['b'] = df['a'].ffill().cummax().astype('Int64')
print (df)
       a     b
0    NaN  <NA>
1  103.0   103
2  101.0   103
3    NaN   103
4  105.0   105
5  107.0   107
6  100.0   107
```

Comment: You can also add `.astype(int)` to the end of that to enforce `b` as an `int`, which would then match the desired output exactly.